# Google Sign In Button Doesn't Appear on SPA

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, google-signin

I'm creating a web app, which is Vue-based SPA and uses Google login, bundled by Webpack.
So I tried to add a sign in button using [this method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin), but nothing shows up.
I figured out that the problem is occuring because Vue needs some time to render, but I have no idea how to fix the problem - I think there will be a way to fix it with Webpack configs, but I'm not familiar with Webpack so I can't.

Comment: Did You tried to take a look at some already existing components and see how it is done there? For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-auth Another thing - try to remove defer attribute form script tag where platform.js loads.

Comment: @monas That package is just providing a programmatic way to do it. Anyway, I should use that package if I can't find any way to solve this.